# Sencha JetBrains Plugin auto insert code, is it correct?

Tags: intellij-idea, extjs

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4, macOS 10.12.5, Sencha JetBrains Plugin 6.0.11.531

I try typing:

```
Ext.define('KitchenSink.store.Books', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    alias: 'store.books',
    model: 'KitchenSink.model.grid.Book'
});
```

Sencha JetBrains Plugin auto insert code, source code become to:

```
Ext.define('KitchenSink.store.Books', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.books',

    requires: [
        'KitchenSink.model.grid.Book'
    ],

    model: 'KitchenSink.model.grid.Book'
});
```

- In Ext JS syntax perspective, is it correct?
- In IDE's editor behavior, is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure this is expected behavior. If you use any store, models and other views in your class you should put them into the requires. It might not be necessary in some cases and it would work without it. But if you want to be 100% correct it should be there to prevent any load errors in the App.

If you don't want this to happen, you can disable it in the Plugin preferences.
Navigate to Settings -> Sencha

[image: sencha plugin settings]